# What is one with my SQL. Counting how many times each month a client comes in the past year

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
SELECT * 
FROM CLIENT
WHERE CLIENT_REG_DATE > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
GROUPBY MONTH(CLIENT_REG_DATE).
```

I put into Apex Oracle and run it and it says

```
SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: maybe it's the decimal point that your SQL command ends with...  maybe you could try a semicolon?

Comment: You might be looking for DATE_ADD(), and since you are going negative, you might want to use DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit).

Comment: Please fix the subject. What exactly do you mean with "*what is one*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is neither a `DATEADD` nor a `getdate()` nor a `month()` function in Oracle.

For a list of all available date functions, please refer to the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#i88891

And statements have to be terminated with a `;`

And if you are using `SELECT *` the group by is definitely not going to work either.

Without specifying in more detail what you want to group it's hard to tell, but start with something like this:

```
SELECT to_char(client_reg_date, 'yyyy-mm'), count(*)
FROM CLIENT
WHERE CLIENT_REG_DATE > add_months(sysdate, -12)
GROUP BY to_char(client_reg_date, 'yyyy-mm')
```

Comment: I would be a little careful with using interval arithmetic like this is that you can get errors in odd cases.  For example, if you try to subtract 1 year from Feb 29, 2012, you'll get an error because Feb 29, 2011 doesn't exist.  If you use `add_months(sysdate, -12)` instead, you'll get Feb 28, 2011 instead.

Comment: @JustinCave: you are right, good point. Thanks. (I always forget that inconsistency)